# Unable to fix Windows 10 Automatic repair

Tags: windows-10

So last night when I was surfing the web, windows crashed and tried to automatic repair but failed. I contacted one of the Microsoft advisors they told me to download windows 10 onto the USB. After that, he told me to plug  my USB (which I had downloaded Windows 10 on) and repair my PC. However, that failed. So then this afternoon, I contacted another advisor he told me to reset this PC but it failed. I then contacted another advisor and tried to perform a clean installation of Windows 10 but that failed. That just rebooted and took me straight back to the start. Any ideas? I tried all the troubleshoot options but none of those helped.

Comment: Could be a hard drive failure. Take out your hard drive and test in on another computer using the manufacturers test program.

Comment: Well, apparently the microsoft advisor gave me the wrong link. Now another MS advisor gave me another link and told me to download the ISO file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to fix the problem. All I've done was that I remove my laptop battery and insert it again and install Windows again. Apparently, this acts like a hard reset.